# t-sql: Return 1 row or everything based on optional paramater

Tags: t-sql, sql-update, optional-parameters

I have a stored procedure that takes a single optional parameter.  If the parameter exists it should update the 1 record, otherwise everything else.  Are there a way to do in with a single SQL statement without using dynamic SQL?

Something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEmployees (@PersonID varchar(10) = null)
  AS
BEGIN 
      UPDATE Employees 
      SET Field1 = 'Changed'
      WHERE (PersonID Is Not Null OR PersonID = ISNULL(@PersonID, '')) --this not 100% yet.
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost there - you need to perform the update on a row with the supplied `@PersonId` or if the parameter **is** `null` (not if it's not, as you currently have). 
Additionally, The `isnull` is redundant, as `null` will return "unknown" (which is not `true`) on any `=` operation.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE UpdateEmployees (@PersonID varchar(10) = null)
  AS
BEGIN 
      UPDATE Employees 
      SET Field1 = 'Changed'
      WHERE (@PersonID IS NULL OR PersonID = @PersonID)
END
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this makes sense.  If I don't pass a param, then the where will actually resolve to something like: WHERE PersonID Is NULL or PersonID = NULL, and then nothing will be updated.

Comment: @user1208908 that was a typo on my part - it should have been `@PersonID IS NULL` (i.e., evaluate the parameter, not the table's column). See my edited answer.